# allocate values to a new column based on logical string matching in data.table

Tags: r, string, data.table, multiple-columns

I have a large dataset of students where there are non-standard naming conventions for honours students. I need to create/populate a new column which will return a Y or N for string matching based on the word "Honours"

That is currently my data looks something like this with over 200,000 students

```
library(data.table)
students<-data.table(Student_ID = c(10001:10005), 
                    Degree= c("Bachelor of Laws", "Honours Degree in Commerce", "Bachelor of Laws (with Honours)", "Bachelor of Nursing with Honours", "Bachelor of Nursing"))
```

I need to add a third column such that after I create a new column 'Honours' the data table way, it will be populated like this:

```
students<-data.table(Student_ID = c(10001:10005), 
                      Degree= c("Bachelor of Laws", "Honours Degree in Commerce","Bachelor of Laws (with Honours)", "Bachelor of Nursing with Honours", "Bachelor of Nursing"), 
                      Honours = c("N","Y", "Y", "Y","N"))
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Also, by data table way I mean:

```
students[,Honours:="N"]
```

Comment: You could do it stepwise for easy reading: `idx <- grepl("honours", students$Degree, ignore.case = TRUE); students[idx, Honours := "Y"]; students[!idx, Honours := "N"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite simple actually

```
students[, Honours := c("N", "Y")[grepl("Honours", Degree, fixed = TRUE) + 1L]]
```

All you need to do is to search for "Honours" using some regex implementation function such as `grepl`, for instance (this isn't a real expression so you can enhance performance using `fixed = TREU`) and then just do a vector subsetting from `c("N", "Y")` according to your findings (a `TRUE`/`FALSE` logical vector + 1L which will convert it to a vector of `1,2` which will be used to substract values from `c("N", "Y")`)

---

Alternatively, if this too hard to read, you can use `ifelse` instead

```
students[, Honours := ifelse(grepl("Honours", Degree, fixed = TRUE), "Y", "N")]
```

---

Of Course, if "Honours" can appear in different case variations you could switch your `grepl` call to `grepl("Honours", Degree, ignore.case = TRUE)`

---

**P.S.**

I will suggest sticking with a logical vector though because you can easily manipulate it afterwards

For example

```
students[, Honours := grepl("Honours", Degree, fixed = TRUE)]
```

Now if you want to select only the guys with "Honours", you can just do

```
students[(Honours)]
#    Student_ID                           Degree Honours
# 1:      10002       Honours Degree in Commerce    TRUE
# 2:      10003  Bachelor of Laws (with Honours)    TRUE
# 3:      10004 Bachelor of Nursing with Honours    TRUE
```

Or the guys without "Honours"

```
students[!(Honours)]
#    Student_ID              Degree Honours
# 1:      10001    Bachelor of Laws   FALSE
# 2:      10005 Bachelor of Nursing   FALSE
```

Comment: You can also use a more simple operator `%like%` from `data.table`, though is a just wrapper over `grepl`.